# Pandas - ValueError: Error parsing datetime string "17-Jan-23" at position 3

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code where I am reading date column:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(array, columns=names)

data[['D_DATE']] = data[['D_DATE']].astype('datetime64')
```

But this is giving me error:

```
ValueError: Error parsing datetime string "17-Jan-23" at position 3
```

Can someone help how can I resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
data['D_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(data['D_DATE'])
```

Indexing a single column with double brackets (`df[['D_DATE']]`) returns a `DataFrame` with one column named `'D_DATE'`. Indexing with a single set of brackets (`df['D_DATE']`) returns a `Series` named `'D_DATE'`. To create a new column in a DataFrame using the form `df[new_col]`, use single brackets.